# Is it possible to sleep a computer from a Chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm interested in running a Chrome app as a system tray utility to receive network commands and be able to put a machine to sleep remotely.

Does a Chrome app have permissions to sleep / hibernate the machine it is running on?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the only thing possible is to keep it awake. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/power

Comment: That's a shame... I hoped maybe I missed something in the API.

Comment: @DanielHerr Please make that into an answer. A negative answer is an answer if you are reasonably sure of it, and as always, _avoid answering in comments_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Chrome APIs only allow the app to prevent the system from sleeping, and to release this restraint, as a commenter mentioned above. They cannot invoke a power action on the system.

Full information is available at the [Chrome.power API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/power).